# What is the syntax of a valid identifier in the Nix language?

Tags: nix

Couldn't find the language specification anywhere, it basically the [Nix source](https://github.com/NixOS/nix)? The repo's README refers to the [Nix manual](http://nixos.org/nix/manual), but it seems incomplete. For example, [4.2. Identifiers](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/basics-of-language.html#idm140737316486672) in Nix Pills mentions that the dash (-) can be used, and the manual never even mentions identifier syntax.

---

*update*: Just found the already closed (and unresolved) [NixOS/nix issue #592 No documentation on valid symbol/variable names](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/592)

Comment: however what is nix?

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Nix, but this is currently written as a request for a link to an off-site resource, and thus off-topic by nature (see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" link at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Much better would be a narrow question about the parser's specific behavior (with a full reproducer, transcript, &c), asking whether and how that behavior is supported by the relevant specification. (Indeed, you've already got an answer that would remain responsive and on-topic with such a reformulation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be better references, but at the very least you can check out the source of the [lexer](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/src/libexpr/lexer.l#L91), which defines an identifier

```
ID          [a-zA-Z\_][a-zA-Z0-9\_\'\-]*
```

as a string consisting of ASCII letters, numbers, `_`, `'`, or `-`, and starting with either a letter or `_`.

---

(Update: this references an out-of-date reference grammar, not the working grammar.)

According to the [grammar](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/doc/manual/nix-lang-ref.xml), an identifier cannot contain a `-`:

```
  <production id="nix.id">
    <lhs>Id</lhs>
    <rhs>[a-zA-Z\_][a-zA-Z0-9\_\']*</rhs>
  </production>
```

but a path can:

```
  <production id="nix.path">
    <lhs>Path</lhs>
    <rhs>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\+]*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\+]+)+</rhs>
  </production>
```

I am not entirely sure what evaluation process leads the REPL to report a syntactically valid path as undefined variable.

Comment: The linked grammar reference is from 2009, and it is not in effect anymore. Just tried on a fresh Nix install (2.2.2) on Ubuntu 19.04 the example in [6.6.1. Build an environment](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-building-environment), but replaced `myPackages` with `my-packages` - no issues. Thanks for digging into it anyway.

Comment: Updated with a link to `lexer.l`, which I assume is actually used to build Nix :)

Comment: Thanks again, especially for the link!